# Server.MapPath does not like ~/ and ./

Tags: asp-classic, vbscript

I am using the following code to try and find a file contained in another directory from my code file.

```
Set fi=fs.OpenTextFile(Server.MapPath("~/counter/counter.txt"), 1)
```

I have also tried.

```
Set fi=fs.OpenTextFile(Server.MapPath("./root/folder1/counter/counter.txt"), 1)
```

In either case this should get me back to the counter.txt file. From what I understand ~/ moves up 1 directory and ./ moves up to the root directory.

Both times however I receive an error saying an invalid character has been used. When removing these I get a different error saying the path cannot be found (Which I would expect because it is not a valid path without moving up 1 directory).

What are the valid characters to do the following in VBscript:
move up a single directory?
move up to the root directory?

Thanks for the help

Answer (score 8, accepted):

A few things:

The tilde character "~" is not valid here.

The single period character "." is for specifying the current directory/folder.

A set of period characters ".." is for specifying the parent directory/folder. For example, to refer to a file found in the parent of the current directory, you might use:

```
Server.MapPath("../counter.txt")
```

You can chain these to walk up more than a single parent path. To refer to a file found three directories above the current, you might use:

```
Server.MapPath("../../../counter.txt")
```

The documentation on MSDN for the [MapPath](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms524632%28v=vs.90%29.aspx) function outlines this. Pay attention to the caution listed here about [enabling parent paths](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms524697%28v=vs.90%29.aspx) if you want to be able to refer to relative paths above the current directory. If you get an error when trying to refer to a parent path, then you do not have parent paths enabled.

Comment: +1 Worth pointing out the the "~" is used in ASP.NET to indicate the root folder of the application but ASP classic doesn't suppor this syntax.

Comment: +1 In addition, paths which starts with a forward slash "/" refers to the application root like `include virtual`. At least in IIS7+, am I correct?